# Inserting Form Data into MYSQL Database using PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having trouble inserting data into the database when my "submit" button is pressed from a form.  I want to take the values inputted from the user and store those values in the table I created

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $link = $_POST['link'];
        $email = $_POST['screenerAmount'];
        $minutes = $_POST['minutes'];
        $comments = $_POST['comments'];

        //insert into table

        $sql = "INSERT INTO test_myFilm (email, link, screeners, minutes, comments)
        VALUES ('$email', '$link','$screenerAmount', '$minutes','$comments')";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            header('Location: submit_ThankYou.php' );
             } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "
        " . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);
    }
?>
```

Here is the form:

```
<div>
                <form  class="submit-film" action="testfilm.php" method="POST">
                    <p class="email">Email</p>
                    <input class="field" name="email" id="email" placeholder="youremail@example.com" required>
                    <p class="project_link">Link to your project:</p>
                    <input class="field" name="link" id="link" placeholder="https://vimeo.com/myfilm" required>
                    <p class="number">How many screeners do you want?</p>
                    <input class="field" name="screenerAmount" id="screenerAmount" placeholder="8 screeners" required>
                    <p class="please">Please attach a questionaire if you have one preparred:</p>
                    <input type="file" class="select">
                    <p class="length">How many minutes is your project?</p>
                    <input class="field" name="minutes" id="minutes" placeholder="15 minutes" required>
                    <p class="questions">Do you have any additional comments or questions?</p>
                    <input class="field" name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="(insert comments/questions here)"> 
                    <div> 
                        <button type="submit" class="button_type" class="button_type:hover" value="Submit" name ='submit'>Submit</button> 
                    </div>  
                </form>
            </div>
```

My connection seems to be working and I am not receiving any error. I am using Javascript to validate the values inputted into the form fields, so I see the values logged to the console, but the page does not refresh when the "submit" button is pressed.

Javascript as requested:

```
const form = document.querySelector('.submit-film'); 
const emailPattern = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/; 
const linkPattern = /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})/; 

form.addEventListener('submit', e=> {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    //validation

    const email = form.email.value; 
    if (emailPattern.test(email)){
        true; 
        console.log(form.email.value); 
    } else if (email === ""){
        alert("Please submit your email address so we can get in contact with you.")
        false; 
    } else {
        alert("You have entered an invalid email address!"); 
        false; 
    }

    const link = form.link.value; 
        if (linkPattern.test(link)){
            true; 
            console.log(form.link.value);
        } else if (link===""){
            alert ("Please input a link to your project. If you do not have a link to your project simply input 'no link'"); 
            false; 
        } else {
            alert("Please input a valid URL for your film. Youtube, Google Drive, and Vimeo work great. If you are still having trouble email contact@entholigy.com for help."); 
            false; 
        }

    const screenerAmount = form.screenerAmount.value; 
    if (screenerAmount==="" || screenerAmount.value === null){
        alert("Please let us know how many screeners you want."); 
    } else {
        console.log(form.screenerAmount.value); 
    }

    // const foo = form.foo.value;
    // console.log(foo);   

    const minutes = form.minutes.value; 
        if (minutes==="" || minutes.value === null){
            alert("Please let us know how long your film is (in minutes)"); 
        } else {
            console.log(form.minutes.value); 
    }

    console.log(form.comments.value); 

}); 

const now = new(Date); 
console.log(now);
```

Comment: You said you're using Javascript to validate the values but you didn't show that code. Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with everything necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It sounds like your JavaScript is preventing the submission.

Comment: Please learn how to use mysqli properly. Even better, learn PDO instead. Good articles can be found here: https://phpdelusions.net/

Comment: Thanks @Dharman I am a beginner with PHP and have every intention of learning PDO. I never thought Javascript would be preventing the submission. I attached the file as requested. Thank you for your assistance

Comment: I believe this `e.preventDefault();` is preventing submission

Comment: Thank you for your response @Dharman. I commented out that line of code in the file and I am still not able to submit the form

Comment: I copied it over to a file and it works for me.

Comment: I brought it over to a private browser and finally got it to work. Thank you so much for your help @Dharman!

Answer (score -2):

Change your submit button to `input` as you're checking for `$_POST['submit']` in your submit page. See if this works for you.

```
<input type="submit" class="button_type" value="submit" name='submit'>Submit</input>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @sauhardnc. Unfortunately this did not work for me

Comment: This won't work. `<input type="submit">` acts the same as `<button type="submit">...</button>`.

Comment: @kmoser that's not true actually. Yes, both of them will submit the form but `$_POST['xyz']` won't give any value because it's not an input field.

Comment: @sauhardnc It doesn't have to be an input field to provide value in POST message.

Comment: @sauhardnc Any `<input>` or `<button>` that has a `name` attribute will cause its `name` and value to be POSTed, e.g.: `<input type="submit" name="foo" value="bar">` is functionally identical to `<button type="submit" name="foo" value="bar"></button>`.